# Makfile usees same cpp file to generate objects

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a project with over 15 cpp files, wich I want to compile with my makefile. The creation of the name for the `.o` files from `objects` works fine, but when creating the actual `.o` file, they are created with the first cpp file from `sources`.

```
cc = clang++

sources = $(wildcard */*/*/*/*.cpp) $(wildcard */*/*/*.cpp) $(wildcard */*/*.cpp) $(wildcard */*.cpp) $(wildcard *.cpp)
objects = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(notdir $(sources)))

flags = -g -Wall -std=c++17
libPath = -L"C:\\Users\\Karl\\Desktop\\c++\\libraries\\GLFW\\lib-vc2019" \
        -L"C:\\Users\\Karl\\Desktop\\c++\\libraries\\GLEW\\lib\\Release\\x64" 
libs = -lglew32 -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lShell32 -lmsvcrt -lgdi32 -lUser32 -lkernel32


all: program.exe

program.exe: $(objects)
    $(cc) -o $(appName) $^ $(libPath) $(libs)
  
$(objects): $(sources)
    $(cc) $(flags) -c -o $@ $<
```

When I execute make it says:

```
clang++ -g -Wall -std=c++17 -c -o renderer.o bridge/duffte-api/glRenderer/sources/renderer.cpp
clang++ -g -Wall -std=c++17 -c -o SHADER.o bridge/duffte-api/glRenderer/sources/renderer.cpp
clang++ -g -Wall -std=c++17 -c -o shaderImpl.o bridge/duffte-api/glRenderer/sources/renderer.cpp
clang++ -g -Wall -std=c++17 -c -o TEXTURE.o bridge/duffte-api/glRenderer/sources/renderer.cpp
```

And so on for every object.

Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: The basic problem is that the line `$(objects): $(sources)` tells `make` that each of the object files specified in `$(objects)` depends on *all* of the source files specified by `$(sources)` of which `bridge/duffte-api/glRenderer/sources/renderer.cpp` is presumably the first (because that's what `$<` expands to).  You probably want a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) but it's difficult to say any more without knowing your source file/directory hierarchy.

Comment: Something must be in the water... are you finding this incorrect method of writing makefiles in a tutorial or something, that we should try to get fixed?